# MYSQL Events not Running, Unable to turn on event_scheduler

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-event

My database (mysql) server is hosted on Mochahost.com . I have created an Event on my database, but its not running. I found that the event scheduler is turned off. I queried the following command

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON
```

but it returned this error

"" `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

I checked and found that I dont have the privilege option available to create a user with Super privileges 
[image]

Please help me how to fix this, do I need to contact the host support for this ?

Comment: Yes, contact your host or move to a dedicated server (more expensive but better since you have total control over the server).

Answer (score 0):

As André said, this is something your host needs to allow (and probably won't in a shared hosting situation). Switching to a dedicated host is probably the only way to get full access to the database.